# How to delete the same data from any two of the four

Tags: sql-server

I have four pairs of the same data.

I just want to delete one of the two and the remaining two are reserved.

Could anyone help me along？

Comment: You can use `rownumber` function. Can you post some data sample and your table structure?

Comment: improve your post by updating code which avoids down vote

Comment: Thank you to help me to solve

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

--If I am understanding you correctly, you are trying to remove duplicates from a table.  The best way to do this is using a cte ( common table expression ).  Here is an example and I hope you can adapt this for your own use.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #TEMP ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),SOMEVALUE VARCHAR(255) )
INSERT INTO #TEMP ( SOMEVALUE )
VALUES ('VALUE1')
,('VALUE2')
,('VALUE2')
,('VALUE3')
,('VALUE4')
,('VALUE4')
,('VALUE4')
,('VALUE4')
,('VALUE5')
,('VALUE6')
,('VALUE6')
,('VALUE6')
,('VALUE7')
,('VALUE8')
,('VALUE8')
,('VALUE9')
,('VALUE10')

;WITH dedup
AS
( 
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOMEVALUE ORDER BY ID ASC) AS SEQUENCE
FROM #TEMP
)
DELETE
FROM dedup
WHERE SEQUENCE > 1
GO

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```